# Why use properties file instead of placing properties as fields in java class?

Tags: java, testing

```
public class ConfigValues 
{   
     public static final String url = "https://www.google.com/";
     ..//more properties
}
```

Why above one is NOT considered good, but creating separate `.properties` file is considered good practice?

Comment: Do you really want to recompile your code every time you want to change the value?  Also, consider properties that need to be different depending on the environment into which they are deployed.

Comment: Not sure why you got obliterated with downvotes...But a simple reason is that when changes need to be made, you would much rather have to make changes to a properties file than to source code. 

Using a properties file avoids having to make changes to source code when properties change or when new ones need to be added. Also no recompilation is required for prop file alterations.

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion based - as the [good answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728846/2513200) showed, it is perfectly possible to give solid technical reasons for this. However, I'm sure there are already multiple duplicates, - my suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801746/properties-file-vs-constants-class-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because Java source file needs recompilation and deployment to make a change.

If your code reads a property file, it's:

- Easier to change the value.
- Allows reading property file from outside jar file (if configured), so it can be changed without changing a deployed jar file.

I mean, you did call it a "configuration value", right?

That implies that you can "configure" it when you deploy the code.