# Constants in Properties File

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

My team is new to Spring Boot and most members were previously working on a J2EE legacy application. I have previous experience with Spring Boot and microservices. My question is about a pattern they are using that I've never seen before and want to understand why this may or may not be a good idea.

They have been creating several properties files and adding key value pairs to these property files which get injected into object fields using @Value or ResourceBundle.

For example something I would normally think of as an Enum like color will be added to a property file, the same with constants.

```
#color.properties
color.r = red
color.b = blue
color.g = green
```

It seems like a lot of unnecessary code is getting written, like injecting all the values into a class then creating an array with the values in them. We are also battling to get this working.

I thought the point of the properties file was for externalized config. Why is my team doing this when Java provides data types and structures for these things?

I suppose the way I would want to do this is by creating Enums and utility classes with static constant fields.

Comment: If those values are not changed frequently and are not "configuration" I do not know why you would store it in properties and not in enum.

Comment: Have you actually asked your team why do they do this? Looks like old injures that have found their way to the modern code :) I also see no reasons not to use Enums here, I also add that this has nothing to do with spring boot in particular...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated the post. For constants would you create a utility class with static fields? I'm just trying to figure out why they think this is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't some Spring Boot reason I was missing out on. I'm thinking it's an old injury as well. I asked the team and didn't really understand their reasoning. I wasn't able to give a good defense of what I think we should do and why I think it is better.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying

> the point of the properties file was for externalized config

Put stuff into properties only if you need to allow this property to be configurable with different values per customer/environment/execution. Even adding some properties that are rarely changed can make your properties excessively large and cumbersome. So if those are constants not meant to be changed they are **DEFINITELY** do **NOT** belong in properties. Either use Enum or put them into an Interface or as `static public` members into abstract class. Call it `Constants` or something like this

Answer (score 0):

Its not the right way,You are right we should use ENUM for such type of constants.

**Normally, properties file is used to store project configuration data or settings**

If you talking about Spring's application.properties then its the worst thing

please go through the below link for best use of Spring's application.properties

[Spring Application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: They are creating additional property files. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @heartAttackGorilla Please go through the below link of Property File vs constant file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801746/properties-file-vs-constants-class-in-java